# Calling super method after over-riding only possible by protected access without argument passing

Tags: java

Trying to understand Java OOP (Python coder predominantly). I wasn't able to call parent class method from child class in the over-ride.
Example:
From Child class Checking account, I'm trying to over-ride parent method, and then if fails call super.method.

```
public String allowWithdraw(Integer amount) {
    if (amount < this.withdrawalLimit) {
        return "Yes";
    } else {
        return super.allowWithdraw(Integer amount);
    }
}
```

Parent class Banking account has allowWithdraw method.

```
public String allowWithdraw(Integer amount) {
    return "No, calling super";
}
```

This fails showing syntax error suggestions. If I have protected access package method additionally to the original one, the method gets called. And, **only** if there isn't any argument passing. I went through resources here, and I'm not able to figure out why.

```
protected String allowWithdraw(Integer amount) {
    return "No, calling super";
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance, OOP or the access modifiers like protected -- its a simple syntactical issue, you don't add a type when *using* a variable - it already *has* a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
return super.allowWithdraw(Integer amount);
```

Remove `Integer` here. You only specify the data type when you declare the function, not when you call it.

Comment: Darn. :/ Thank you.